# Writing all lines from a file to a file UNTIL it reaches a specific string

Tags: python-3.x

```
f = open("Trades.txt","r")
writer = open("trading.txt","w")
options = input("A:Check trades for 1 or more players/B:Check trades between 2 players: ").lower()

if options == 'b':
    player1 = input("Enter the name of player 1: ")
    player2 = input("Enter the name of player 2: ")
    for lines in f:
        if player1 and player2 in lines:
            writer.write(lines)
```

Text file looks something like this:

```
=======================
[time] player trading with playerx
(To: player, From: playerx)
item
=======================
[Jan 13, 2016 11:53:49 PM Central European Time] y trading with x
(To: x, From: y)
item
=======================
```

The user will be asked to enter 2 names to find in the text file.

These 2 names will have to be found in the text, which I have done.

Then, the lines AFTER the line with the names will have to written to a file UNTIL it reaches "=======================".

So the written data would look something like:

```
[time] player trading with playerx
(To: player, From: playerx)
item
```

Thanks in advance

P.S The number of lines after the names will vary so can't write like a set amount of lines after the match

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. Please show us your attempts at tackling this problem and ask precisely about issues you're encountering.

Comment: I have? Take a look at the first bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: That has nothing to do with reading a file and writing until it reaches something...

Answer (score 0):

two things to fix

first

```
if player1 and player2 in lines:
```

is wrong, probably this is better

```
  if player1 in lines and player2 in lines:
```

To stop when the ======================= is found in a for loop something like

```
lines = lines.strip()
if lines == '=======================':
  break
```

The "strip()" function removes the newlines from the input file so an exact match on the line works correctly

Just to make it clear the code

```
for lines in f:
    if player1 and player2 in lines:
        writer.write(lines)
```

is replaced with

```
for lines in f:
  if player1 in lines and player2 in lines:
    lines = lines.strip()
    if lines == '=======================':
      break
  writer.write(lines)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I add the extra code given by you?

Comment: I've added more detail on where the changes are added

Answer (score 0):

Since source file object is an iterator, you may consume it anywhere, not only in `for line in f` statement.

To consume iterable until condition occurs you may use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function.

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true.

`takewhile` will create new iterable, but as a side effect source iterable will be consumed. In file object case - it'll read lines and move internal file pointer. After exhausting `takewhile` iterator, internal file pointer would point to first line after `===`.

Code would be similar to something like:

```
import itertools

player1 = "x"
player2 = "y"
with open("Trades.txt") as src, open("trading.txt", "w") as dst:
    for src_line in src:
        if player1 in src_line and player2 in src_line:
            dst.write(src_line)
            for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda s: not s.startswith("======================="), src):
                dst.write(line)
```